# How to set image url in html from typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building ionic app for wallpaper/gallery.I want app to show wallpaper in full screen when user clicks on a particular image.

Thanks.

HTML code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Walldo</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-slides zoom="true">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
      <img id="fullwall" src="some link">
    </div>
    <ion-label>Elephant</ion-label>
    <button ion-button round (click)="download('wall.jpg')">Download</button>      
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

TYPESCRIPT code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-popular',
  templateUrl: 'popular.html',
})
export class PopularPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PopularPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: You may want to show us your code so that we can help you?

Comment: @Yogesh,i don't get why you need code for this?Anyway i included code.

Comment: So that someone who's answering will do so by modifying it or pointing out the mistakes in it instead of writing it from scratch (At least I would do that).

Comment: `<img [src]="theWallImageUrl" />`, and in the code: `this.theWallImageUrl = ...`. Simple property binding.

Comment: @Yogesh,i understand your point.I'm just asking how to set img url from typescript dynamically?Now tell me how to do that.

Comment: @JB Nizet,thanks a lot.Simple and effective.Post that as answer,so i can mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple property binding:

```
<img [src]="theWallImageUrl" />
```

and in the code of the component:

```
this.theWallImageUrl = ...
```

Comment: Can you also tell me,how to set dynamically set ion label?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: JB Nizet In question html there is <ion-label>Elephant</ion-label>.How can i set what is given between <ion-label> from typescript?

Comment: So you want `<ion-label>{{ someLabel }}</ion-label>`? and in the component: `this.someLabel = ...`? You're asking basic questions about angular. You won't go very far if you don't take time to learn the framework. This is probably the very first things you normally learn about it. Read the documentation, or a good book (like https://books.ninja-squad.com/angular)

Comment: JB Nizet thanks for the link,i know what you are trying to say.I'm 2 days experienced in this.So,i'm fresh in this.